# Изменить кодировку текста на UTF-8

Tags: php, кодировка

У нас есть какая-то страница. Её кодировка не известна. Как нам переделать кодировку текста в UTF-8?

Точнее известна (она в мета-данных), но она неправильно там указана. Поэтому брать оттуда информацию будет глупо - получаются на выходе кракозябры.
Т.е. такой вариант не работает:

```
preg_match('|charset=(.*)"|Uis', $html, $char);
$charset = iconv($char[1], "UTF-8//IGNORE", $html);
```

Comment: в хиадер, Content-Type зрите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему с помощью этого: [charset_x_win](http://popoff.donetsk.ua/text/work/libs/a/charset/).
Действия: делаем windows-1251, из windows-1251 с помощью `iconv` перегоняем в utf-8.

Comment: Мсье знает толк в извращениях

Comment: Ваш вариант отображает ту же кодировку: windows-1251